System.Net.Sockets.Stream Throws System.StackOverflowException
_readResult throws error when message is not received from TCP client.
I have a TCP client that is communicating with my server and this works fine, all message work well, but when I disconnect the client, I get a System.StackOverflowException and i get the flowing:

at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at VisualShot.TargetServer.Models.Communication.TcpMessageReader.readCompleteCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToAsyncResult+TaskAsyncResult..ctor(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Object, System.AsyncCallback)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToAsyncResult.Begin(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at VisualShot.TargetServer.Models.Communication.TcpMessageReader.readCompleteCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToAsyncResult+TaskAsyncResult..ctor(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Object, System.AsyncCallback)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToAsyncResult.Begin(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at VisualShot.TargetServer.Models.Communication.TcpMessageReader.readCompleteCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToAsyncResult+TaskAsyncResult..ctor(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Object, System.AsyncCallback)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToAsyncResult.Begin(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
at VisualShot.TargetServer.Models.Communication.TcpMessageReader.readCompleteCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter+<>c.<OutputWaitEtwEvents>b__12_0(System.Action, System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(Int32)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1+ValueTaskSourceAsTask+<>c[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<.cctor>b__4_0(System.Object)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs+<>c.<.cctor>b__173_0(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolTypedWorkItemQueue`2[[System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+IOCompletionPoller+Event, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+IOCompletionPoller+Callback, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

C# Code
private bool _reading;
private Stream _stream;
private TcpClient _client;
private IAsyncResult _readResult;
private bool _disposed;

private byte[] _parseBuffer = new byte[0];
private byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
private int _maxBytesRead;

private void readCompleteCallback(IAsyncResult readAsyncResult)
{
    if (_reading)
    {   
        Stream stream = (Stream)readAsyncResult.AsyncState;
        int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(readAsyncResult);

        if (bytesRead > _maxBytesRead || bytesRead == _buffer.Length)
        {
            _maxBytesRead = bytesRead;
        }
        
        byte[] newParseBuffer = new byte[_parseBuffer.Length + bytesRead];

        _parseBuffer.CopyTo(newParseBuffer, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
        {
            newParseBuffer[i + _parseBuffer.Length] = _buffer[i];
        }
        _parseBuffer = newParseBuffer;


        // Parsing
        int bytesConsumed = MessageFactory.GetNextMessages(
            _parseBuffer,        // buffer
            0,                  // msgReadStart
            _parseBuffer.Length, // totalBytesAvailableToConsume
            out var messages);

        newParseBuffer = new byte[_parseBuffer.Length - bytesConsumed];
        for (int i = bytesConsumed; i < _parseBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            newParseBuffer[i - bytesConsumed] = _parseBuffer[i];
        }
        _parseBuffer = newParseBuffer;

        _readResult = stream.BeginRead(
            _buffer,
            0,
            _buffer.Length,
            new AsyncCallback(readCompleteCallback),
            stream);
    }
}

trying to handle disconnect and reconnect to TCP client

looks like a "stack dive", there is a good example of what goes on in this blogpost. Maybe after reading the relevant parts (if still unsure) you can amend your code to include a bigger chunk of the call stack.

Short fix:
if(bytesRead <= 0) {
  // EOF
  return;
}


IAsyncResult has a CompletedSynchronously property; the idea is that if you could stack-dive like this, you check for this, and short-circuit doing nothing in the callback, and also check it in the original caller, invoking the required code synchronously instead. This avoids the stack dive.
However! You can avoid the problem much easier by using the await stream.ReadAsync(...) API instead. The Begin* / End* pattern predates modern runtime/language features that make this much, much simpler.
To be explicit: the stack dive at the moment usually happens when lots of reads end up completing synchronously via data in the buffer, because you're keeping up with inbound data. It never goes truly async, so your callback is executed synchronously, does another read, etc etc. but in your case it looks like you're not checking the read-bytes for EOF, i.e. a non-positive number of bytes read. Same side-effects.

I rewrote the class to use async Task instead of IAsyncResult and I used the if(bytesRead <=0) {return;} and this worked

It looks to me like you are calling the function you are inside of in that final call to BeginRead here:
    _readResult = stream.BeginRead(
        _buffer,
        0,
        _buffer.Length,
        new AsyncCallback(readCompleteCallback),
        stream);

That would be recursive, which means it will call into itself in a loop. There is no exit condition for this recursive call loop so it goes on forever until the stack overflows.
Try removing the new AsyncCallback(readCompleteCallback), from that read call and the issue should disappear.
